# Network monitoring ping

Tags: bash, loops

i am reading from a txt file several hundred ip addresses, want to ping the list to the end of the file.  would like this to run in a loop instead, read to the end of the file, then  start at the first address again.

```
trap 'echo ****Interrupted****; exit'INT

echo -n "Enter the file name with the ip addresses"
read file

echo -n "Enter the file name for the log file"
read log

while read line
do
echo "pinging: "$line
echo -e "">>$log
echo -n "NEXT PING: ">>$log
echo -n "$line" : " >>$log
$ping -c 3 -W 2 $line >>$log
done <"$file"
```

Comment: wrap your while loop in another while loop with a `true` conditon. Maybe `while true ; do while read line ; do ...... done < "$file" ; sleep 5 #?; done` Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fping`.

http://fping.org/

From the `fping` man page:

```
DESCRIPTION
   fping  is  a  program  like ping(8) which uses the Internet Control Message 
   Protocol (ICMP) echo request to determine if a target host is responding.
   fping differs from ping in that you can specify any number of targets on the 
   command line, or specify a file containing the lists of targets to ping.
   Instead  of  sending  to  one target until it times out or replies, fping will
   send out a ping packet and move on to the next target in a round-robin
   fashion.
```